# What is this type of function called? How can I translate it to a different origin?

Tags: combinatorics, finite-differences

A factory produces 1 widget per week. A builder builds 1 factory each week. A construction firm trains 1 new builder each week. Partially-produced things do not produce anything. Starting with 1 firm, how many of each thing will there be after $t$ weeks?

If we let ${n \choose k} = 0$ for $k > n$, then we find that:

$$
\begin{align}
\text{firms: } f_3(t) &= 1 &= {t \choose 0} \\
\text{builders: } f_2(t) &= t &= {t \choose 1} \\
\text{factories: } f_1(t) &= 1,3,6,10,\ldots &= {t \choose 2} \\
\text{widgets: } f_0(t) &= 1,4,10,20,\ldots &= {t \choose 3} 
\end{align}
$$

In general: if at week $t_0$ we have $k_0$ widgets, $k_1$ factories, $k_2$ builders, and $k_3$ firms (and so on), then how many of each do we have $t$ weeks after $t_0$?

$$
\begin{align}
%f_i(t) &= &=& \sum_{j=i}^n {t \choose j-i} k_j \\
f_3(t) &= k_3 &=& \sum_{j=3}^n {t \choose j-3} k_j\\
f_2(t) &= k_2 + {t \choose 1}k_3 &=& \sum_{j=2}^n {t \choose j-2} k_j \\
f_1(t) &= k_1 + {t \choose 1}k_2 + {t \choose 2}k_3 &=& \sum_{j=1}^n {t \choose j-1} k_j \\
f_0(t) &= k_0 + {t \choose 1}k_1 + {t \choose 2}k_2 + {t \choose 3}k_3 &=& \sum_{j=0}^n {t \choose j}k_j 
\end{align}
$$

How can we translate this to a new origin $t_1$? That is, what $K$ values can we use for the derived function $F$ so that $F_0(t) = f_0(t-t_1)$? I would expect it to work with $K_i=f_i(t_1)$.

When I define $f$ with $k$ values $[4,3,2,1]$, I find that $f(5) = [49,33,12,1]$. But if I define $F$ with those $K$ values, I get:

$$
\begin{align}
f_0(8) &=& 4 + 3{8 \choose 1} + 2{8 \choose 2} + 1{8 \choose 3} &= 140 \\
F_0(3) &=& 49 + 33{3 \choose 1} + 12{3 \choose 2} + 1{3 \choose 3} &= 185
\end{align}
$$

What's going wrong here?

Edit: I see now that I shouldn't have been trying to use the intermediate calculations for $f_i$ as shortcuts to $f_{i+1}$. When I calculate each $f_i(5)$ independently I get $K=[49,23,7,1]$, which gives $F_0(3)=140$, as expected.

Is there a name for this type of function? What kind of literature can I consult to find more like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They appear to be forms of *Newton's interpolating polynomials*, special cases of  Newton's Forward Difference Formula for equally-spaced points (viz., $x_i \in \{ 0,1,...,n \}$):

$$P(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{x}{k}\Delta^k f_0
$$

where $\Delta^k f_0$ denotes the forward differences corresponding to an interpolated function $f$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Declaring the rates of change $k_i$ axiomatically is equivalent to taking them from measurements.